# Inject presenter - Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

i can problems to inject my presenter on the fragment and i dont know why, i think i'm doing everything correctly and i'm a bit desperate.

The error is as follows:

```
Error:(20, 10) error: com.drivero.locationreminder.presentation.main.presenter.ReminderListPresenterImpl cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.
com.drivero.locationreminder.presentation.main.presenter.ReminderListPresenterImpl is injected at
com.drivero.locationreminder.infrastructure.di.module.PresenterModule.provideReminderListPresenter(presenter)
com.drivero.locationreminder.presentation.main.presenter.ReminderListPresenter is injected at
com.drivero.locationreminder.presentation.main.fragment.ReminderListFragment.presenter
com.drivero.locationreminder.presentation.main.fragment.ReminderListFragment is injected at
com.drivero.locationreminder.infrastructure.di.component.ViewComponent.inject(reminderListFragment)
```

This is my component:

```
@ViewScope
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class,
        modules = {ViewModule.class, PresenterModule.class})
public interface ViewComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

    void inject(ReminderListFragment reminderListFragment);
}
```

This is my modules:

```
@Module
public class ViewModule {
    private Activity activity;
    private Fragment fragment;

    public ViewModule(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public ViewModule(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Provides
    @ViewScope
    Context context() {
        return activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @ViewScope
    Activity activity() {
        return activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @ViewScope
    Fragment fragment() {
        return fragment;
    }

    @Provides
    @ViewScope
    Navigator navigator() {
        return new Navigator(activity);
    }

}

@Module
public class PresenterModule {

    @Provides
    @ViewScope
    ReminderListPresenter provideReminderListPresenter(ReminderListPresenterImpl presenter) {
        return presenter;
    }

}
```

this is my presenter:

```
    public interface ReminderListPresenter extends Presenter<ReminderListView> {

    void onClickCreate();
}

public class ReminderListPresenterImpl extends BasePresenter<ReminderListView> implements ReminderListPresenter {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ReminderListView view) {
        super.initialize(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickCreate() {
        navigator.goToCreateReminder();
    }
}
```

And my fragment:

```
@ViewScope
public class ReminderListFragment extends BaseFragment implements ReminderListView {

    @BindView(R.id.reminderList)
    private RecyclerView reminderList;
    @BindView(R.id.floatingActionButton)
    private FloatingActionButton createReminderButton;

    @Inject
    ReminderListPresenter presenter;

    public static Fragment getNewInstance() {
        return new ReminderListFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        presenter.initialize(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutContainer() {
        return R.layout.fragment_reminder_list;
    }

    @Override
    public void initializeInjector() {
        buildInjector(new ViewModule(this)).inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to inject a RemainderListPresenterImpl.  That means that some function in your modules must provide a RemainderListPresenterImpl, or the RemainderListPresenterImpl must have a constructor marked @Inject.  Otherwise it doesn't know how to construct one to inject it.  This could be as simple as a 0 argument constructor with no body that's marked @Inject.